# (vscode) Nothing happens when I press ctrl+f5

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

There is no response except for a momentary 1 appearing in `Run and Debug` on the left. Originally, the console window should be running, but why not?
I completely uninstalled vscode and reinstalled it. Even if I try to run any `.py` from any folder, it is only possible with a button click, not a shortcut key.

Comment: What does your code look like? How long does it take to run if you run it in the console?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Doesn't seem to launch regardless of the code (.py)